# Save String value of class variable

Tags: java, string

```
package Store;

public class Child extends Parent {
    private String test = "";

    public void ontest() {
        this.test = "tryyyysssssssssss";
        System.out.println("in constructer: " + this.test);
    }

    public String gettt() {
        System.out.println("in child: " + this.test);
        return this.test;
    }
}

public abstract class Parent {
    Parent() {
        ontest();
    }
    public void ontest() {

    }
    public String get() {
        System.out.println(gettt());
        return "test";
    }
    public abstract String gettt();
}


public class StoreString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child s = new Child();
        System.out.println("vaaaa:" + s.get());
    }
}
```

output is:

```
in constructer: tryyyysssssssssss
in child: 
vaaaa:test
```

My question:

I would like to use saved value of attribute test in `Child` class in method `getttt()`. I am not sure why value of `test` is blank in `gettt` method.
Could any one help me what is missing here?

Comment: private String test = ""; ?? This is a empty string in the child class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the default initialization of the test String:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    private String test;

    @Override
    public void ontest() {
        test = "tryyyysssssssssss";
        System.out.println("in constructer: " + test);
    }

    @Override
    public String gettt() {
        System.out.println("in child: " + test);
        return test;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child s = new Child();
        System.out.println("vaaaa:" + s.gettt());
    }

}

abstract class Parent {
    Parent() {
        ontest();
    }

    public abstract void ontest();

    public String get() {
        return gettt();
    }

    public abstract String gettt();
}
```

Output:

```
in constructer: tryyyysssssssssss
in child: tryyyysssssssssss
vaaaa:tryyyysssssssssss
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java, field initialization happens *after* the call to the parent constructor. So whatever value you assigned in the parent constructor by calling the overridden method is going to be overwritten by your initializer.

Reference: [Java Language specification item 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), specifically, the list of five steps.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the `test` is empty is, the flow of execution when creating the instance:

1. Parent constructor is invoked
2. Child.ontest() is invoked (initializing the variable)
3. (parent fields are initialized - nothing to do)
4. (Child constuctor is invoked - nothing to do)
5. Child fields are initialized - overrides the previously set field `test` with the empty String

So you may either remove the default value `""` which will leave the field as is (namely, initialized with `"tryyyysssssssssss"` by the Parent constructor) or explicitly invoke `ontest()`

Answer (score 1):

Change `String test="";` to `String test;`

```
    public class Child extends Parent {
        private String test;

        public void ontest() {
            this.test = "tryyyysssssssssss";
            System.out.println("in constructer: " + this.test);
        }

        public String gettt() {
            System.out.println("in child: " + this.test);
            return this.test;
        }
    }

    public abstract class Parent {
        Parent() {
            ontest();
        }
        public void ontest() {

        }
        public String get() {
            System.out.println(gettt());
            return "test";
        }
    public abstract String gettt();
}


public class StoreString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child s = new Child();
        System.out.println("vaaaa:" + s.get());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
in constructer: tryyyysssssssssss
in child: tryyyysssssssssss
tryyyysssssssssss
vaaaa:test
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is the execution Order given by the [JLS 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5). That´s what actually happening.

Explicity quoting the important rules here

> [...]
>
> 3:  This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using super).
>
> 4: Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class.
>
> [...]
>
> Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor
> invocation recursively using these same five steps. [...]

The following is now happening due to the given execution order of object initialization. You´ll find the problem in the last step as it reassigns `test` in `Child` again.

```
main starts -> Child s = new Child(); 

Child invokes Parent Constructor as first super call

Parent constructor call method ontest(). 

ontest -> this.test = "tryyyysssssssssss"

Parent constructor prints "tryyyysssssssssss"

Child constructor continues and initalises the default values and sets this.test = ""
```

as @swinkler already said, if you remove the default intialization of `test` the last step wont set `test` to an empty `String` again.

Answer (score -3):

The constructor for Child should start with: `public Child() {`

Comment: The problem is not because of a missing constructor

Comment: Thank you all for quick response